# Async logging with RollingRandomAccessFileAppender

Tags: logging, slf4j, log4j2

I get the following error using RollingRandomAccessFileAppender.
I use Slf4j with log4j2.

log4j2.xml has the following config:

```
     <RollingRandomAccessFile name="rollingApp" fileName="/opt/applogs/server-war.log" filePattern="/opt/applogs/server-war-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" 
            immediateFlush="false" append="true" ignoreExceptions="false" >
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ddMMyy HH:mm:ss} [%X{correlationId}] %p (%c{1.}-%M:%L) - %m%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10KB"/>
    </Policies>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile >

  </appenders>

  <loggers>
    <Root level="info" includeLocation="true">
    <appender-ref ref="rollingApp"/>
    </Root>
  </loggers>
```

[image: Error Log below]

Any pointers?

Also, Same config works on a windows server. Not on linux.

edit:
Only RollingRandomAccessFile  poses the issue, works fine with RollingFile appender

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is, does the user that the process is run under have permission to write to that directory?

Comment: Yes, full permission.

Comment: What version of Log4j2 are you using? Is it possible there are multiple versions of Log4j2 on the classpath?